# XCOFF binary editor

Tags: aix, patchelf

Is there a tool for editing a built XCOFF file?
I'd like to specify the path to some dependencies after the build, just like the -bipath flag does when XCOFF is linked.
I'm looking for something like patchelf, only for AIX and XCOFF.
I found https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=l-ldedit-command, but it doesn't seem to be able to do it

Comment: Try relink it: `ld -bipath -o newexe oldexe sharedlibraries`